# How to assign a 1D numpy array of length x to an element of length y of a 2D Numpy Array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a way to assign a 1D numpy-array consisting of x elements to a 2D numpy Array of shape (y,z).

Example:

```
A=np.array([[0],[0],[0]])
A[2]=np.array([0,2])
```

Which should result in

```
A=[[0],[0],[0,2]]
```

This works perfectly fine using a python list, but has been causing me huge trouble when trying to do it in numpy, usually resulting in the error message:

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (z) into shape (x)
```

This seems to occur as a result of the fact that numpy copies everything  instead of modifying the array in place. I have only recently begun using numpy and would really be grateful if someone could help find a way to do this efficiently.

Comment: Your A result is not a matrix. Matrices (which is what numpy's ndarray type is for) have full grids of numbers, e.g. every row has the same length and cannot contain object references. Sparse matrices have some of the cells empty, but the places still exist. Numpy hardly copies everything and their dog but has a specific purpose, where contigious memory is a net positive (for one thing, a numpy array of floats typically takes less than one third the space of a Python list of floats, and additionally gains cache locality with adjacent entries - even vanilla Python has arrays for such reasons).

Comment: @YannVernier I understand that this operation should be possible if I simply filled A to be something like A=[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]] since then the length of A[2] would match that of the array I want to have at that position.

Comment: However, I cant just use a matrix full of zeros, since I could afterwards not say which elements of the matrix are the "default" zeros and which ones i might have inserted myself. I would love to do the whole thing simply using python lists but the library im working with to plot my data uses numpy, and converting the lists seems to take a long time.

Comment: You could fill your matrix with numpy.NaN (not a number), but it's quite likely the plotting library won't like them.

Comment: What I ended up doing was filling the matrix with 0s and then introduce a global variable which marks the position of the newest "added" datavalue in the matrix, allowing me to clearly see which part is my data and which is the default 0s. Still thx a lot for the deeper insight into what I was doing to numpy and why that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the issue is that Numpy *refuses* to perform implicit copies or reshapes. For instance:

```
>>> A=np.array([[0],[0],[0]])
>>> A[2]=np.array([0,2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1)
```

Here `A[2]` is a subarray of A, of shape 1. 2 cells can't fit in 1, so we get shape error. The reverse situation is possible and known as broadcasting:

```
>>> A[0:2]=5
>>> A
array([[5],
       [5],
       [0]])
```

Here a single scalar has been broadcast to update the entire subarray. We can resize A to be able to fit the shape 2 entry:

```
>>> A.shape
(3, 1)
>>> A.resize((3,2))
>>> A.shape
(3, 2)
>>> A[2]=np.array([0,2])
>>> A
array([[5, 5],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 2]])
```

We can see that the resizing actually reorganized our cells. It still starts with 5 5 0 but the cells are no longer along a single column. This is because numpy doesn't copy unless asked to, either; all of our multicell slices in fact refer into the same original array. We can make a second matrix and copy the original into a single column there:

```
>>> B=np.zeros((A.shape[0]+1,A.shape[1]))
>>> B[:,0]=A.transpose()
>>> B
array([[ 5.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
```

The transpose is because the slice of B is 1-dimensional shape (3 long) rather than a 2-dimensional shape like A (which is 1 wide and 3 high). Numpy considers the 1-dimensional array to be a horisontal shape, so a 3 wide and 1 high matrix will fit. You could think of it like copying a range of cells in a spreadsheet.

Notably, the numbers thus placed in B are copies of what was in A. This is because we did a modification of B. Views can be used to manipulate sections of a matrix (including seeing it in another shape, like transpose() does), for instance:

```
>>> C=B[::-1,1]
>>> C
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> C[:]=[1,2,3]
>>> B
array([[ 5.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```